# ClearCanvas - How to reinventory studies moved to different drive letter?

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

I recently inherited managing a [ClearCanvas](http://clearcanvas.github.io/) server, and am coming up to speed on the application.

The server has two FileSystems defined on two different drive letters:

- C:\ClearCanvasFS\Primary\ <-- Read, Write, Tier1
- F:\ClearCanvasFS\Primary\ <-- Read, Tier1

Apparently, at some point in the past, it looks like the former system administrator manually moved a bunch of studies from the C:\ drive over to the F:\ drive. I suspect he moved them manually through the Windows operating system, not within ClearCanvas. I have confirmed that the necessary DICOM folders and files all exist on the F:\ drive.

The studies that were moved from C:\ to F:\ still appear in the ClearCanvas database, but when we try to route or view any of those studies, the images cannot be found (because they were manually moved to the F:\ drive).

Additionally, when I "View Details" on any of the moved studies, and go to its "Study Storage" tab, the "Study Folder" still lists the original C:\ drive location, instead of the F:\ drive location where it was manually moved to.

Is there a way for me to force ClearCanvas to rebuild or refresh its database, to properly reflect the correct path for those studies that were manually moved to the F:\ drive?

I discovered the "Filesystem Inventory" method under the Admin > System Scheduling tab. If I run the Filesystem Inventory task against the F:\ClearCanvasFS\Primary\ filesystem, will that update all of the database records for those studies, without creating duplicates and auto-routing again?

Would I also need to run the "Filesystem Rebuild Study XML" method as well, or instead?

We have tens of thousands of studies and many TB of data, so I'm hoping to find an automated method to simply update/remap the "Study Folder" paths for each study. Manually editing paths study-by-study is not a good option for us. I'm also hoping to avoid having to copy or move any of the study DICOM files/folders, since there is such a large amount of data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Study Reinventory option in the Service Scheduling page was intended to cleanup databases after this type of problem.  It should update the database entries for the study to point to the new location/filesystem.  You should be able to just enable this entry, and it will schedule itself and run over an extended period of time.  There should be little impact on the rest of the system when this is running.

I would suggest starting with running the entry for the F drive, and then spot checking some of the studies to ensure they are now pointing to the new location.

The rebuilding of the Study XML file should not be required.  The running of the reinventory also does not require moving of any of the files.